# Creating GraphServiceClient without client Id and using tenant Id

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

```
final ClientCertificateCredential certificateCredential = new ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder().clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).pfxCertificate(certPath).clientCertificatePassword(certPassword).httpClient(httpClient).build();

final AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider(certificateCredential, null, SCOPE);
return new GraphServiceClient(authProvider, okHttpClient);
```

I need to provide the client Id while creating the credentials for graphServiceClient itself.  I have two sites (prod site and non prod site) under the same tenant ID. I know the site names for both sites are different. But for production I don’t know the client Id yet. Do I need to hard code the client Id (based on environment) always or is there a way to fetch it using the site name or tenant ID, so that I would not hard code it in the code.

Please help.